What would be the best tool to simulate FTIR spectra of molecules?
I tried to simulate a spectrum of a porphyrin using the orca 5.0.4 program, calculating the frequencies and simulating the spectrum with the orca_mapspc program from the orca package, however the spectrum did not resemble the experimental one even using the recommended exchange and correlation functional and a set of indicated bases: wb97x-d3 and def2-TZVP.
Since the experimental FTIR spectrum of this molecule was made on a solid KBr tablet, and the calculation was in the gas phase, would it be better to simulate the spectrum in the solid phase also with the quantum espresso program?
Edit: Added experimental FTIR and DFT plots:


Could you provide details on exactly how and where the experimental and computational spectra disagree? For example, are the peaks systematically shifted? Are any experimental peaks missing in the calculation? Does the calculation give narrow peaks where the experimental peaks are broad? etc.

just to add to this, please just include both spectra here.

There are several reasons why your simulated spectrum might be inaccurate, and several reasons why it will be inaccurate.
It might be inaccurate because:

The density functional method you are using might not simulate vibrational spectra accurately. Always be aware that DFT methods are severely temperamental, and are only good for what they are parameterised for (i.e., if you want to calculate accurate geometries of molecular complexes, there will be several functionals to pick from, but it is unlikely they will calculate accurate frequencies). As far as I know, none of the DFT researchers churning out new functionals have parameterised their latest work for frequencies, so you really are rolling the dice as far as picking something which will accurately predict the system you are looking at.

As you say, you are calculating the spectrum for a gas phase molecule but recorded the experimental spectrum in KBr, so environmental effects might play a role. It's possible that simulating the KBr (by either explicitly surrounding your porphyrin with KBr molecules in the calculation, applying an electric field gradient across your molecule, or running a full AIMD simulation) could improve your theoretical spectrum, but there is no guarantee. It would, at the very least, be worth looking at the infrared spectrum of KBr to check where its absorbances are (I'm assuming you did not record the spectrum of an empty KBr pellet and subtract that from your porphyrin spectrum, which would also be a good idea...).


It will be inaccurate because:

You have calculated your spectrum using the harmonic approximation. This means that, in addition to your calculated peaks always being about 10% higher than they should be, you are not simulating overtones or combination bands in your spectrum. You are also not taking any resonance effects into account, which, experimentally, can cause splitting to occur between peaks, as well as intensity 'sharing'. If you want a more-accurate spectrum, you would have to run a calculation using Molpro, Gaussian, NWChem, GAMESS, or any other program which has an anharmonic treatment of vibrations implemented (VPT2 and VSCF are the common methods).

Finally, compared to the amount of work done trying to calculate accurate energies, methods to calculate accurate vibrational frequencies and intensities are being developed by very few research groups—as such, there is no reliable method which can be used to reliably simulate an infrared spectrum.


Overall, if you have the resources and the access, I would suggest you run an anharmonic frequency calculation first and see what that gives you. I would also look up whether the functional you are using is appropriate for simulating vibrational frequencies, and possibly switch to a different one if it looks like ωB97X-D3 performs particularly badly. Benchmarking studies are useful for that kind of thing.
